# error SQL al crear tablas. "no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «post»

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo este error al querer crear una serie de tablas en SQL, solo pondre las 3 tablas que estan involucradas en el error (ya he comprobado que son estas).

```
CREATE TABLE pagina (
    idpagina SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    texto VARCHAR(480),
    nombreusuario VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (nombreusuario)
    REFERENCES usuario(nombreusuario)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE blog (
    idblog INT,
    idpagina INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (idblog,idpagina),
    FOREIGN KEY (idpagina)
    REFERENCES pagina(idpagina)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE

);

CREATE TABLE post(
    idpost INT,
    idpagina INT,
    texto VARCHAR(480),
    fecha DATE,
    hora TIME,
    idblog INT,
    idfoto INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (idpost, idblog),
    FOREIGN KEY (idblog, idpagina)
        REFERENCES blog (idblog, idpagina)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (idfoto)
        REFERENCES foto(idfoto)
        ON UPDATE SET NULL
        ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Creo que el error está en la clave foranea de post (que son ambas PK de blog) pero no puedo hacerlo funcionar de ninguna manera.

Gracias

Comment: En la tabla de post, coloca las 3 en la llave primaria PRIMARY KEY (idpost, idblog, idpagina), así asegura un unique para esa tabla.